# wrapping selection in a tag shortcut in brackets mac osx

Tags: macos, emmet

Hi all I'm trying to figure out how to wrap a selection with an html tag in brackets w/ emmet. No luck so far and I've searched through all documentation but nothing works. Seems simple enough to have been included and documented but nothing so far. Im on a mac os btw.

Comment: Check out `Emmet` menu item

Comment: i did but i didnt see what i was looking for. What would it be called there?

Comment: Wrap With Abbreviation? http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Answer (score 1):

I use **Shift+command+A**, and then  inside the input text I insert the html elements as short words like

ul>li.item$*5